# Converting FGDC XML to ISO XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xslt, lxml

Just wanted to know if was possible to convert an XML from one standard to another using an XSLT transformation file.  I am trying to convert FGDC metadata to ISO 19139.  I have an XSLT that should be able to transform it.

If it is possible, is there something I am missing with the following code?

```
from lxml import etree


f_xml = 'U:\\PROJECTS\\FGDC2ISO\\A08727.mxd.xml'
f_xsl = 'U:\\PROJECTS\\FGDC2ISO\\ISO2.xslt'
f_out = 'U:\\PROJECTS\\FGDC2ISO\\A08727_ISO.mxd.xml'

transform = etree.XSLT(etree.parse(f_xsl))
result = transform(etree.parse(f_xml))
result.write(f_out)
```

Here is a link to the xslt 
**EDIT link now good:**

http://service.ncddc.noaa.gov/rdn/www/metadata-standards/metadata-xml/documents/csdgm2iso19115-2.xslt

Sample of XSML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gmi="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmi" xmlns:gmx="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmx" xmlns:gsr="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gsr" xmlns:gss="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gss" xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vmf="http://www.altova.com/MapForce/UDF/vmf" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:grp="http://www.altova.com/Mapforce/grouping" xmlns="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmi" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="fn grp vmf xs xsi xsl">
    <xsl:template name="vmf:vmf1_inputtoresult">
        <xsl:param name="input" select="()"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$input='POINT'">
                <xsl:value-of select="'point'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$input='PIXEL'">
                <xsl:value-of select="'point'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$input='GRID CELL'">
                <xsl:value-of select="'area'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$input='VOXEL'">
                <xsl:value-of select="'area'"/>
```

Comment: The link to the stylesheet does not work.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have edited the link.  Should work now.  I have been running into the error lxml.etree.XSLTParseError: Invalid expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of an XSLT transformation is a tree object and not string. Hence you need to convert to string before output to file. You can even pretty print the output even specify encoding with `tostring()`:

```
transform = etree.XSLT(etree.parse(f_xsl)) 
result = transform(etree.parse(f_xml)) 
xmlstr = etree.tostring(result, encoding="iso-8859-1", pretty_print=True)

with open('Output.xml','wb') as f:
  f.write(xmlstr)
```

Comment: Thanks Parfait, I am getting the error below when running that script.



>>> 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 254, in run_nodebug
  File "<module1>", line 19, in <module>
  File "src/lxml/xslt.pxi", line 409, in lxml.etree.XSLT.__init__ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:173339)
lxml.etree.XSLTParseError: Invalid expression
>>>

Comment: lxml.etree.XSLTParseError: Invalid expression

Comment: There's an issue with the XSLT script. Please post a snippet. As reminder, Python's lxml can only run XSLT 1.0 scripts.

Comment: Just posted XSLT script sample in the original question as well as updated working link.  I see it does say version="2.0", not sure what this is in reference to though.

Comment: after looking carefully, it does look like it is XSLT version 2.0.  Are there any alternatives in that case?

Comment: Indeed, you are trying to run an incompatible version as if/then logic among others are not allowed in XSLT 1.0, the first version of language. Since then there have been 2.0 and recently 3.0 but these have not been universally accepted especially for browser support. You need Python to pass xml and xsl file via command line to a pre-installed standalone xslt processor such as Saxon and Xalan. See [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info).